# How to run multiple files in the same directory with the same text program using R and store the output in different name?

Tags: r

I have this code that reads an excel file from a folder executes a routine and stores some outputs in excel in a specific folder.
How can I achieve to run with the same code all the input excel files in a folder and get output in different names?
The code only differs each time for each file only in the part it loads the file and the name of the input file and the name of the outputs.

The related parts are the following;

```
## read excel file (or write a path or do that via the menu)
data <- read_excel("C:/Users/thoma/Desktop/PATENTS EU/raw data/PC_PATENTS/patents input to code_48_PC/2010_48_PC.xlsx")

#Save results
#save the 2nd matrix transformation
write_xlsx(C3, "C:\\Users\\thoma\\Desktop\\PATENTS EU\\CODE RESULTS\\PATENTS_PC\\48\\2ndtable_48_PC_2011_B.xlsx")
#save the rca matrix transformation
write_xlsx(MCp, "C:\\Users\\thoma\\Desktop\\PATENTS EU\\CODE RESULTS\\PATENTS_PC\\48\\RCA_48_PC_2011_B.xlsx")
#save the MPP matrix transformation
write_xlsx(dfMPP, "C:\\Users\\thoma\\Desktop\\PATENTS EU\\CODE RESULTS\\PATENTS_PC\\48\\MPP_48_PC_2011_B.xlsx")
#save the MCC matrix transformation
write_xlsx(dfMCC, "C:\\Users\\thoma\\Desktop\\PATENTS EU\\CODE RESULTS\\PATENTS_PC\\48\\MCC_48_PC_2011_B.xlsx")
#save the Complexity country estimates
write_xlsx(cmplx_Country_Ind_output, "C:\\Users\\thoma\\Desktop\\PATENTS EU\\CODE RESULTS\\PATENTS_PC\\48\\cmplx_Country_Ind_output_48_PC_2011_B.xlsx")
#save the Complexity product estimates
write_xlsx(cmplx_product_Ind_output, "C:\\Users\\thoma\\Desktop\\PATENTS EU\\CODE RESULTS\\PATENTS_PC\\48\\cmplx_product_Ind_output_48_PC_2011_B.xlsx")
```

How can I write a script that executes the code by altering these two parts?

Comment: Write a finction that takes the name of an input Excel file as its only (or first) input and produces the (file specific) output you need.  Call this `myFunc`.  Obtain a list of input files.  Call this `fileList`.  The `lapply(fileList, myFunc)` does what you want.  It's difficult to be more specific since we don't have acces to your C drive and you haven't specified the processing you want between input and output.

Comment: The process in between performs a lot of actions; it's a generic process that produces an index from scratch. The only thing that changes each time is loading the input and exporting the output, that is why I presented these parts.